# Using masking in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have a thesis that I'm writing about Ice coverage change on rivers, and I decided to use Google Earth Engine for this.

I have an algorithm already that can check if the pixel is icy or not. But the problem is I have to mask this to only calculate it on rivers and not anywhere else.

I have a limited knowledge of `JavaScript` and looked up the `API` to find a solution for masking. I tried to incorporate the example into my code but it gives me an error *"updatemask"* is not defined in this scope.

So how do I define this mask? Because at the moment I just create a variable that contains area of a river and assign it to a mask.

```
var datamask = ShapeFile;      // Uploaded.
var mask     = datamask.eq(1); // As I understand this is where you tell the mask which part to use.
var dif      = updatemask(datamask);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, the function is named `updateMask`. Second, it is an instance method for an `ee.Image` object, which returns another `ee.Image` object. So you need to set the mask for a particular image. Assuming you may have an image which represents ice, you might do something like

```
// I am assuming you are loading this via ee.FeatureCollection etc
var datamask = ShapeFile;      
var mask = datamask.eq(1); 

var ice = ee.Image(<some ice asset>);
var masked_ice = ice.updateMask(mask);
```

Comment: Is possible to get the masked percentage like maskedimgarea/imagearea in a defined roi?